# Bridging React Native and Swift Classes with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, reactjs, react-native

I am bridging React native and Swift Modules. I have completely done that. I am trying to add my existing IOS project and wanted to add in React Native.

For instance, When i create a new project for ReactNative. My Current Project become

> ReactNative/ios
>
> Now Is there any way to export the IOS project directly in the folder and make a reference to call from React Native ?

Comment: You need to expose your native methods to React-Native in order to use them in React-Native

Answer (score 0):

You can bridge native with react native. you can either import modules from either side or create buttons and shift your control to each side. 
- You can create a button in RN and call Native module or complete project. please have look at this link

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios.html

Hope this helps. I will be most probably developing a project which allows you to bridge 2 apps by one button with complete documentation.

Comment: I have solved the bridging, i used this example http://browniefed.com/blog/react-native-how-to-bridge-an-objective-c-view-component/